# SharePoint 2013 Alert showing incorrect values of Metadata fields

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, alert

When we configure SP out of box alert it is sending incorrect values of Managed metadata fields in email

Few points -

1, These fields are not available to edit on form

2. Document Library is created in code. List definition is created with custom fields / content type and site columns in code.
3. We have a event receiver on the library, where item updated event is setting correct value of managed metadata field (confirmed)
4. Email alert is showing wrong values of managed metadata fields but on checking again in library, correct values are set (most probably by event receiver)
5. I have a feeling that internal column IDs are muddled up because of custom code and that is confusing Alert

Need help -

1. How to troubleshoot as how and from where Alert is picking up incorrect values of these fields ?
2. Any other suggestion where to check (database?) and how the working of Alert can be checked.

Comment: Firstly are these bad metadata proper metadata values of another documents or its random? Can you empty whole library and start with one document or create new library (ID will start at 1) and test it here?